# "Multipart/form-data" is not woking in React-redux form upload

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, redux, axios

I am facing some problem in getting the file upload value from input type `file`.
what I am getting is the file path name but I want to get the whole path for uploading it into cloudinary.
When I am sending data from `postman` `form-data` it is working fine but through frontend I am not getting that unexpected result.

any suggestion what I can change here ?

//Blog.js

```
class BlogModal extends Component {
    state = {
        modal: false,
        blog_short_desc: '',
        blog_image_url: '',
        blog_by_author: ''
    }

    static propTypes = {
        auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired
    }

    onChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({ [e.target.name] : e.target.value });
    }

    onFileChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({ [e.target.name] : e.target.files[0] });
    }

    onSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const FileName = this.state.blog_image_url ;
        
        const newBlog = {
            blog_short_desc: this.state.blog_short_desc,
            blog_image_url: FileName,
            blog_by_author: this.props.auth["user"].name
        }
        console.log(newBlog);
        //Add item via addItem action
        this.props.addBlog(newBlog);
        alert("Blog added successfully!");
    }
    render(){
       
        return(
            <div>
                <Form onSubmit ={this.onSubmit } enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <FormGroup>
                        <Label for="blogHeading">Blog Heading</Label>
                        <Input type="text" name="blog_short_desc" id="blogHeading" placeholder="Add one liner"
                        onChange={this.onChange} required/>

                        <Label for="blogImageURl">Image Url</Label>
                        <Input type="file" name="blog_image_url" id="blogImageURl" placeholder="Add image url "
                        onChange={this.onFileChange} />

                        <Button color="dark" style={{marginTop: '2rem'}} block>Add blog</Button>
                    </FormGroup>
                </Form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    resume: state.resume,
    auth: state.auth
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { addBlog })(BlogModal);
```

//action

```
export const addBlog = blog => (dispatch, getState) => {
    
    const config = {
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        }
    }
   axios
   .post('/api/blogs', blog, tokenConfig(getState), config)
   .then(res => 
    dispatch({
        type: types.ADD_BLOG,
        payload: res.data
    })).catch (err => dispatch (returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status)));
    
};
```

//router

```
router.post('/', upload.single('blog_image_url'), async (req, res, next) => {

    try {
    const result = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(req.file.path);
    const newBlog = new Blog({
        blog_short_desc: req.body.blog_short_desc,
        blog_name: req.body.blog_name,
        blog_desc: req.body.blog_desc,
        blog_image_url: result.secure_url,
        blog_by_author: req.body.blog_by_author

    });

    await newBlog.save().then(blogs => res.json(blogs));
    next();
    } catch (error) {
        next(error);
    }
});
```

//tokenconfig

```
// setup config/headers and token
export const tokenConfig = getState => {
        //Get token from local storage
        const token = getState().auth.token;

        // headers
        const config = {
            headers: {
                "content-type": "application/json"
            }
        }
    
        //if token then add to headers
    
        if(token) {
            config.headers['x-auth-token'] = token;
        }
    return config;
};
```

//current value in network panel

```
blog_by_author: "Tanmoy Sarkar"
blog_desc: "fddgdfgfd"
blog_image_url: {}
blog_name: "sirirrrheyyy siri"
blog_short_desc: "How I learned the Ups & downs"
```

//Expected value ( now via postman set through form data)

```
{ asset_id: '9f271dc05712daf92b05702d95549c5a',
[0]   public_id: 'bia1qqug7bkrz1n29wai',
[0]   version: 1595352697,
[0]   version_id: '632b918f3b664cee4661e7c124786e8c',
[0]   signature: '981e2cc7c5e90a7cf8adf517cb79513132737f60',
[0]   width: 675,
[0]   height: 505,
[0]   format: 'jpg',
[0]   resource_type: 'image',
[0]   created_at: '2020-07-21T17:31:37Z',
[0]   tags: [],
[0]   bytes: 211385,
[0]   type: 'upload',
[0]   etag: '269901e75a4d992a40c2507e884b5a2b',
[0]   placeholder: false,
[0]   url:
[0]    'http://res.cloudinary.com/tammycloudinary/image/upload/v1595352697/bia1qqug7bkrz1n29wai.jpg',
[0]   secure_url:
[0]    'https://res.cloudinary.com/tammycloudinary/image/upload/v1595352697/bia1qqug7bkrz1n29wai.jpg',
[0]   original_filename: 'tmp-1-1595352688726' }
```

//from network panel
[image]

//content type is still `application/json` with empty file object

[image]

//Working with postman form-data

[image]

Comment: e.target.files[0]

Comment: Hi @epascarello I ahve tried this but it returns with 
VM11115:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: means it is not a file input. You are going to have to make a different change event handler for text and file.

Comment: Any suggestion with my current code ?

Comment: @epascarello your suggestion worked ...

Comment: wbut I am unable to get the Tempfile. Which will be required for uploading it into cloudinary.

Comment: I have no clue how that library works for uploading files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I'm guessing you're using `multer`, if I'm right, you gotta use `req.file` instead of `req.files.blog_image_url` since you defined it as a `single` file, in multer docs there is an example:

```
app.post('/profile', upload.single('avatar'), function (req, res, next) {
  // req.file is the `avatar` file
  // req.body will hold the text fields, if there were any
})
```

also, you want to make sure that request has a `Content-Type` header with the value of
"multipart/form-data".

axios accepts config object as the third parameter, and there's no support fourth parameter. probably you're returning an object in `tokenConfig(getState)` which contains a `header` object, so you gotta merge that with:

```
headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
}
```

Comment: Hi stackedQ , Thanks for your time. I have tried to set `content-Type: multipart/form-data` in my action.js but still I am getting with `application/json`. Any suggestion here. I ahve updated my code as well.

Comment: What happens in tokenConfig?

Comment: It is defined as `application/json` for whole project. I have updated my code.

Comment: This solved my problem of multipart. but I am still getting file as

`blog_by_author: "Tanmoy Sarkar"
blog_desc: "sfdsfdsfsf"
blog_image_url: {}
blog_name: "sirirrrheyyy "
blog_short_desc: "Hey " ` 

Any suggestion for this ?